# finding values of corresponding columns in a query using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains donation history (id, transdate, amt to simplify) and I need to calculate some totals. Some of them I can get using the max and min functions but others I'm having trouble pulling out.  What I need is:

ID

Number of donations

Sum of all donations

First Donation Date

First Donation Amt (need help)

Last Donation Date

Last Donation Amt (need help)

Largest Donation Date (need help)

Largest Donation Amt

I have everything except the ones that say need help.

Here is a simplified table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Donations](
    [ID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Amount] [money] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is some data

```
insert into Donations Values('12','3-21-2009',25)
insert into Donations Values('12','3-10-2010',25)
insert into Donations Values('12','11-21-2012',100)
insert into Donations Values('12','5-25-2013',150)
insert into Donations Values('12','6-15-2014',150)
Insert into Donations Values('17','1-1-2014',500)
insert into Donations Values('26','12-23-2007',100)
insert into Donations Values('26','5-22-2013',150)
insert into Donations Values('26','2-11-2015',500)
```

Here is the query I'm using

```
SELECT     ID, 
               COUNT(ID) AS Donation_count, 
               SUM(Amount) AS SumofDonations, 
               MIN(TransactionDate) AS FirstDonation_date, 
               MAX(TransactionDate) AS LastDonation_date, 
               MAX(Amount) AS LargestDonation_Amount
FROM         dbo.Donations
GROUP BY ID
```

Here are my results so far

ID..Count.Sum...FirstDt.....LastDt....LargestAmt

12...5...450...03-21-2009...06-15-2014...150

17...1...500...01-01-2014...01-01-2014...500

26...3...750...12-23-2007...02-11-2015...500

Can anyone help me pull the First Donation Amt (corresponding to First donation Date), Last Donation Amt(corresponding to Last donation Date), and Largest Donation Date (corresponding to Largest Donation Amt)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you have more than one transaction on a single day? Do you intend to record your transactions down to the second?

Comment: Yes, we do track it that way.  This was just a simplified version of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries. For example

```
SELECT         [First Donation Amt] = (SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM Donations b WHERE b.ID=a.ID ORDER BY TransactionDate),     
               ID, 
               COUNT(ID) AS Donation_count, 
               SUM(Amount) AS SumofDonations, 
               MIN(TransactionDate) AS FirstDonation_date, 
               MAX(TransactionDate) AS LastDonation_date, 
               MAX(Amount) AS LargestDonation_Amount

FROM         dbo.Donations a
GROUP BY ID
```

For each needed fielded you just grab the top value from the subquery order appropriately. That's probably the simplest.